# Connecting OV2640 with 17 Pins Binocular Camera module, to any microcontroller (System clock on module pin 18 -NC)

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, i2c, serial-data, camera

These pins are on the module:

- 3.3V
- GND
- VSYNC
- SCL
- SDA
- HREF
- D0-D7
- DCLK
- PWDN
  I have tried many codes and connections of the OV7670 Monocular cameras, none seem to work([Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/OV7670-Without-FIFO-Very-Simple-Framecapture-With-/) ,  [Circuit Digest](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/how-to-use-ov7670-camera-module-with-arduino) , [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bfY9JXOppI)).
  The binocular cameras seem to be just daisy-chained using the I2C SCCB interface. I cant get any image reading on any of their codes provided. Some other guides mention programming the XCLK on board using SCCB PLL, but I'm not sure how to do it as I don't have much background in this domain.

Edit:-

1.[Another resource](http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/07/hacking-ov7670-camera-module-sccb-cheat.html)

2.[Wiki with datasheet and schematic](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Maix_Binocular_Camera) (the module is a copy of this camera)

[image: Image of module]

Comment: please add a link to the camera datasheet to your post ... do **not** put link into comments